# Sequelize Create/Post with M:N

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to implement a M:N Association with Sequelize.
For this I took a look at the documentation ([doc](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/advanced-many-to-many.html)) and found something very similar to my use case:

```
User.belongsToMany(Profile, { through: User_Profile });
Profile.belongsToMany(User, { through: User_Profile });
```

Now I would like to have an endpoint, which allows me to add a **new** User with a list of **existing** Profiles. (Or the other way around). So e.g.
{
"id": 4,
"username": "p4dm3"
"profiles": [
{
"id": 6
},
{
"id":4
]
}

However, as far as I can tell, the documentation only mentions the case of not existing Profiles with the include statement. Of course I could first create a new user and in the next step create the associations, but I think for transaction handling it would me more convenient to do this in one step. Furthermore, my issue is very similar to the one described [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6458) .
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no user, you'll have to create that first and then you can save the existing profiles to it with a sequelize helper:

```js
const profiles = [profiles]
const user = await User.create(req.body)
user.addProfiles(profiles)
```

Comment: So it is not possible to directy include a list of existing profiles in the User.create?